# Laravel Sass include in html

Tags: css, laravel, sass

i'm having little problems with including scss file in my blade file (layout) of Laravel. I have created file named ie.scss in resources\assets\sass\ie.scss, but i have no idea how this file will create in public\css directory so i can't include it in blade file. I want to include it like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/ie.css') }}" />
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1) In file resources/assets/sass/app.scss I added line :

```
@import "my_app.scss";
```

which is located in the same directory(but that could be path) with scss definitions.

Comment: Yes, but this is separate css file for Internet Explorer users only, are you sure it will work?

Comment: In this case you can use if statement and then use @import

Answer (score 0):

You may use Laravel Mix to compile your `scss` file which will get converted into `css` file. Use this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix.

When you are done with compiling, you may use the following code to fetch the `css`  file in your view.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ mix('ie.css') }}" />`